# Is MathJax in titles a problem? And why?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, question-titles

I think the title is self explanatory. I certainly think it looks nicer. I thought it still worked for searches too, as long as it's something $\ce{H2SO4}$ or $\ce{K}_i$ - certainly does on my browser.

Comment: I think it's fine. On Math.SE, most of the questions are like that.

Comment: See the discussion on http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/253/should-we-revisit-the-url-slug-issue for more details.

Comment: When you use something like Google or Bing, the \ce confuses the engine and it also makes the title look ugly.

Comment: Yeah I see the problem :-)

Comment: Mathjax even executes in profile section.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It can be rather problematic, and we ask that you do it only when the extended markup is *really needed* for the meaning of your question in the title. That might be quite often, depending on the questions you ask, we just ask that you consider it.

Titles are a major part of how search engines index our content, so not only are the displayed results skewed when results turn up, it causes some posts *not* to turn up in results that should have produced them. We use tags as part of the title which curbs this effect a bit, but really good questions can sometimes hide behind markup heavy titles in Google.

It's not that we're worried about SEO here, it's a usability / legibility thing primarily. And, well, of course we want our most relevant content shown in results, that's why we maintain it :)

Answer (score 10):

When you attempt to use the right-click context menu options to either *Open in new tab* or *Open in new window* on a title written in MathJax, the appropriate context menu does not appear as expected.

Another related minor problem with titles that are written in MathJax occurs if the *Zoom Trigger* is set to *Click* (right click on any MathJax formula → Math Settings → Zoom Trigger → Click), which may be useful when reading very small exponents or subscripts.
In this case, left-clicking a title written in MathJax does not follow the link to the question but – as designed – shows a zoom view of the title.