# Are you confused by confusing question titles including the word "Confusion"?

Tags: discussion, editing, question-titles, buzzwords, site-cleanup

*You have guessed it: Buzzwords!*

---

Long story short - as you can look up the tradition of these posts below - please add ***Confusion*** and its derivatives to the list of words that need to be fought as they are just filler words for the title field.

There certainly are a couple of legit uses, e.g. [Confusion about direction of dipole arrow in alpha-helices and other molecules](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/33379/4945), but most of them are like 
[Confusion with the Periodic Table](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/34549/4945) or [Rate and order confusion](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/9270/4945), etc.. You can easily find them by entering [title:confusion](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=title%3aconfusion) into the search box (or clicke-di-click the link).

One obligatory disclaimer quote from season one courtesy of our [fearless leader](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/users/73/jonsca):

> This is no emergency, but it would be nice to have descriptive, googleable titles for these so that people can find them in the future.

Keep an eye out for these, thanks...

---

**Previously on ネバ・マインド・ザ・バズワドズ**

1. [I question the use of "question" in question titles](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/524/4945) 
   ([search here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Aquestion))
2. [Help make help questions have more helpful titles](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/549/4945) 
   ([search here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Ahelp))
3. [Houston, we have a "Problem" in question titles](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/566/4945) 
   ([search here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Aproblem))
4. [Buzzwords in question titles - season 4 & 5 - experiments and exercises](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/583/4945) 
   ([search here for experiments](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Aexperiment))
5. Season 5
   ([search here for exercises](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Aexercise+))
6. [I am asking about chemistry, you know, that's why I put it in the title](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3001/4945) 
   ([search here for chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Achemistry) and [here for chemical*](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Achemical*))
7. [I have a doubt about "doubt" in doubt titles](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3389/4945) (search [title:doubt](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=title%3adoubt))

Spin-off

1. [Can we edit out unnecessary "statements of weakness" or buzzwords inside the questions' bodies?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/593/4945)
2. [Improper question titles/questions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2861/4945)

Comment: Japanese looks a lot like a bunch of people holding hands.

Comment: @M.A.R. we always cross the road holding hands.

Comment: I am insensibly excited for the EN->JP Duolingo course that's hopefully launching next month.

Comment: BTW, Mart, I added this to my [buzzwords query](http://data.stackexchange.com/chemistry/query/654396/questions-possibly-with-chem-se-buzzwords-in-the-title).